# How to initially configure Vault with Quarkus Devservices

Tags: quarkus, hashicorp-vault

I'm building an application using Vault to store a key-value pair in a secured way.
When running Quarkus in dev mode, devservices is starting a Vault container for me including a user setup.
Beside the user, I also need to add a policy as well as the key value pair. Does anybody know how to add this configuration when booting Vault through devservices?
I saw there is a Quarkus configuration property:

`quarkus.vault.devservices.init-commands`

But I never managed to get this executed.

Comment: Can you add your applications.properties configuration for vault.devservices? what is the command string you use?